# Custom sorting of datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm using the following code snippet to sort the datagridview using sortOption that is selected from a drop down menu - deadline or priority.

I've got the deadline option working nicely. However I think the priority option is just sorting it aphabetically at the moment but I want rows with High priority to be displayed first, then medium, then low in the TaskTable (datagridview)

Any ideas please?

```
private void sortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sortOption; // selected sorting method

            sortOption = sortComboBox.Text;

            switch (sortOption)
            {
                case "Deadline":
                    TaskTable.Sort(TaskTable.Columns["Deadline"],
                    System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending); // sort by deadline, nearest first.
                    break;
                case "Priority":
                    TaskTable.Sort(TaskTable.Columns["Priority"],
                    System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending); // sort by priority - high, medium, low

                    break;
```

Comment: DataGridView is winforms NOT WPF

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra row for each type like 1, 2, 3 and sort it using that row (hidden row). Mechanically assign number to each type and sort using that integer.

Answer (score 0):

So the priority values you defined are 'high', 'medium' and 'low'? If this is the case you should define a hash table, a new structure or something like that to provide users abtract values like 'high', 'medium' etc but to make sure it is sorted correctly (alphabetically, i.e. depending on the actual hex value).

high 1
medium 2
low 3

Additional rows will get the job done, too, but I don't think it's the best option. You should encapsulate the actual value and their respective keys. Just in case the requirements change it will be much easier for you to match them.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really `WPF`, **do not** sort `DataGrid`, but sort binded data, which usually much easier to achieve.